# : AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007

Tags: anchor, oracles, anchor-accounts

I'm trying to pass a switchboard aggregator as an account to my anchor program. However I encounter the following error:

```
 Error: AnchorError caused by account: aggregator. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.
```

Program log: Left:
Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Program log: Right:
Program log: SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f

Not sure why the program is expecting it to be owned by the system program, but how can i remedy this?

Comment: Can you show me source code for integration part and the program code? And also the error logs, It seems you sent wrong account with your transaction.

Answer (score 1):

When the owner is `11111111111111111111111111111111`, that usually means the account is not initialized.